# Filter `git show <commitId>` result with file extension

Tags: git, file, patch

Consider a very big changeset. Upon doing `git show <sha1>`, you get changes related to all files. But I am interested only in changes made to `.cpp` files, rest files are not useful for my analysis.

How can I filter them out of `git show` result?

Any command or option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git show -- *.cpp` works. Without `--`, the glob seems unable to work properly.

Comment: Slight correction: `git show -- **/*.cpp`. Otherwise, this won't show changes made to files in directories. This does assume you're in the root folder for the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the diff which `git show` outputs by providing paths or patterns to match. So in your case:

```
git show "*.cpp"
```

You need to use the appropriate quoting for your shell to ensure that Git sees the wildcard (`*.cpp`) and that it isn't expanded by you shell first.

Comment: I did something like this : `git show 29a9f891fd0fdba5c16c8a31ee6cb0cd05b865ad '*.cpp' > D://patchforTransmission.cpp` . Didn't work!

Comment: It looks like you may be using windows, depending on your shell, the correct form of quoting may be different.

Comment: @SauravSahu: I've changed my answer to use double quotes which work in a few more environments, perhaps yours. Which shell are you using to run your Git command?

Comment: @SauravSahu: Single quotes will work in bash so there is another issue which is not evident from the details in your question.

Comment: I get this error message on using single/double quotes : `fatal: ambiguous argument '*.cpp': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: That suggests there were no changes to files named `*.cpp`. What does `git show --name-status` print?

Comment: There are changes to .cpp files. That command shows .cpp file.

Comment: `git show -- *.cpp` can work. Without `--`, the glob seems unable to work properly.

Comment: @ElpieKay: interesting, that implies a bug (failure to retry with glob expansion if the argument does not work as a commit specifier).

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by @ElipieKay in comment section worked for me.

Prints file names having .cpp extension.

```
git show --name-status 29a9f891fd -- *.cpp
```

Display the changes done to files with .cpp extension.

```
git show 29a9f891fd -- *.cpp
```